# How to use @GetDocField in IBM Lotus Domino for a database different than the current

Tags: formula, lotus-domino

I need to "compute when compose" a field in a document so Client+Formula are the only options I have here.

I am using a @DbLookup("" :"NoCache";"server" :"db" ;"View" ; "key" ; fieldName); command that looks into a different server/database and comes back with a UNID of a specific document. The UNID is valid for the server/db database, not the current one. How can I use this UNID to fetch/set a value on the remote document.
In IBM documentation I only found @GetDocField(UNID,fieldName) and @SetDocField(UNID, fieldName, value) that are for the local DB only!!!

How can one actually meaningfully use this UNID since it represents a document on a remote database. I searched for 40 minutes for an answer!

Comment: If you have a view that is indexed by UNID in the target database, you can use DbLookup as the equivalent of GetDocField. But as Torsten says below, there is no equivalent of SetDocField outside of the current database. You will need to invoke LotusScript (or Java) code in order to do that.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible using formula language. 
In LotusScript you can use

```vb
Dim db as New NotesDatabase( "server" , "db" )
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Set doc = db.getDocumentByUnid( uuid )
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue( "fieldname" , value )
```

if you really are not able to use lotusscript in the context you have (normally there IS an option to use LotusScript wherever / whenever you need it, you probably only try to use the wrong context / event / whatever), then the possibility would be to write a litte LotusScript- Agent with the above code and hand the uuid to it via notes.ini- Parameter, profile- document or whatever fits best for you.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is too low to comment, so I have to resort to posting an answer to add a thought.  Have you tried @UpdateFormulaContext?

```
UNID := @DbLookup(...[ReturnDocumentUniqueID]);
@Command([OpenDocument]....UNID);
@UpdateFormulaContext;
@SetDocField(@DocumentUniqueID; ...);
```

@UpdateFormulaContext definitely allows you to reset the 'current' document (from the IBM Domino Designer Help):

```
tempDate := @GetDocField(@DocumentUniqueID;"CreatedDate");
@Command([NavPrev]);
@Command([EditDocument]);
@UpdateFormulaContext;
@SetDocField(@DocumentUniqueID;"nextCreated";tempDate)
```

*"You can use @UpdateFormulaContext to extract values from or set values in external documents. You can even access document- and database-specific information using functions such as @DbName, @DbTitle, @Created, @DocumentUniqueID, @GetDocField, @GetField, @GetProfileDocument."*

Worth a punt.